# Table design for keywords

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, rdbms

I have a many keywords and there are a list of words associated with each keyword

Say keywords are SCIENCE , COMPUTERS, STRUCTURES

There are a list of words under each keyword like

SCIENCE - botany , zoology, physics .....

COMPUTERS - databases , operating systems, .....

STRUCTURES - stacks, queues, arrays, ....

I need to store this in my database, what is a good design for this? Storing them in a single table seems stupid as they are not related to each other, but creating different table seems like a overhead too! So here I am confused.

Comment: Do you have just two levels (keywords and words) or can the words be further subdivided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do.

```
Category (ID, NAME)
  1  Science
  2  Computers
  3  Structures


SubCategory(ID, CATID, NAME)
  1  1  botany
  2  1  zoology
  3  2  databases
```

`CATID` in `subcategory` is a foreignkey referencing the `ID` in `category` table.

Comment: It is not "overhead" to store the data for correctness. The two-table method suggested here lets you keep things straight, making for app code that is easier to write, debug and maintain.  In other words, less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about "relations" in the wrong way. While it's true that botany is not related to databases (except in some very, very rare corner cases), you're looking at the *data*, not the *thing*.

How you model this depends on how you're viewing these keywords. Is this a strict single-parent relationship, where a child keyword can *never* have children and child keywords are fundamentally different from parent keywords (in other words, the parents serve only as a classification mechanism and are not, themselves, keywords)? Or could you "nest" these keywords arbitrarily deeply and use them as keywords at any level (in other words, "botany" might have children, and "SCIENCE" is just as much a keyword as "botany" is)?

If it's the first, you'd want to model it something like this:

```
Category
----------
CategoryID (PK)
Name

Keyword
---------
KeywordID (PK)
CategoryID (FK)
Name
```

If it's the second, you'd model it something like this:

```
Keyword
---------
KeywordID (PK)
ParentKeywordID (FK)
Name
```

Where `ParentKeywordID` is a nullable foreign key back to `Keyword`. You've created a table that references itself, and structures like this define a tree structure with nodes that can be nested at any level.

#### Side note

Many will tell you that storing `null` values in the database is a bad idea, and I would agree with these people in general. If you truly want to go to a fully normalized storage format (normalized to 5NF, anyway), you'd have to do it like this:

```
Keyword
-----------
KeywordID (PK)
Name

KeywordParent
-------------
KeywordID (PK, FK)
ParentKeywordID (FK)
```

Then your top-level keywords simply would not have rows in `KeywordParent`.

This sort of design is generally regarded as "better" from a database design perspective, though it will slightly complicate your queries (only in their construction; they won't perform any worse, and may actually perform *better* without nullable columns).

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyWords (ID, PARENT, NAME)

1 null Science 
2 null Computers
3 null Structures
4  1   botany
5  1   zoology
6  2   databases
```

Typical Tree structure.